# How can I find out the name of an element in a directive?

Tags: angularjs

In my directive:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
```

and HTML:

```
<textarea style="height: 350px; width: 98%"
          data-ck-editor
          data-editor-size="wide"
          data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
          data-ng-model="modal.data.notes"
          name="notes"></textarea>
```

Is there a way that I can access the name that I have assigned to the element?

Comment: you mean : `attr["name"]` ? http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/TmZwb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to all the attributes in you `attr`

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
           console.log(attr);
           console.log(attr['name']);
           /* etc */
```

Answer (score 2):

Either/both of the following should work:

```
elm.attr("name")
```

or

```
attr.name
```